# can not link library files

Tags: ros, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ubuntu natty 11.04 and i am trying to use external library: ueye_api while using ueye camera to capture frames and publish them as ros messages by creating a node roscam

To include external library files I made the necessary changes in CMakeLists.txt file:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(roscam src/roscam.cpp)
link_directories(/usr/lib /usr/local/share/ueye/ /usr/include /usr/local/share/ueye/ueyeusbd)
include_directories(/usr/lib /usr/local/share/ueye/ /usr/include /usr/local/share/ueye/ueyeusbd)
target_link_libraries(roscam libueye_api libueye_api.so libueye_api.so.1 libueye_api.so.3.82)
```

But still I received following error while compiling a program:

```
 Linking CXX executable ../bin/roscam
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibueye_api
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibueye_api.so.1
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibueye_api.so.3.82
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11193/can-not-link-library-files/) by [abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1080/abhinav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The linker cannot find the libraries in the directories you specified.
Where are the files located?

You can check with `VERBOSE=1 make` what the exact linker line is. There should be an entry like `-L<dir to library> -l<library_name>`.

Your cmake file should only need to contain `include_directories()` for the directory where the header files are (e.g. /usr/include, and other system includes should not need to be listed here).
`link_directories` should only contain the directory where the library files are.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1080/abhinav/) on 2011-09-13**:
Yes it should because I was initially trying to link it with some unnecessary library files which it could not find anyway.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-13**:
actually /usr/include shouldn't be required

**Comment by [abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1080/abhinav/) on 2011-09-13**:
Thanks!! it is working by removing the link_directories() command and in include_directories() by removing the unnecessary directories and just keeping /usr/include which contains the header file. And also the libraries libueye_api.so.1 and libueye_api.so.3.82 are not required